# Can't launch Google Play Store from within other apps

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android, intents

Recently, I am having a problem with my Android phone. Generally, when an app tries to show something in the Play Store, the Play Store app opens up. But, recently I noticed that Play Store is no longer opening up from other apps, instead, I get an app chooser which asks me to choose between the two browser apps installed in the phone.
Screenshot:
[image]

When I choose a browser app from the app chooser, then also Play Store doesn't launch.
So, I think that the system can't find the Play Store app. What to do?

*I have Micromax Q437 mobile with Android 7.0*.

Comment: Check open by default setting for Play Store under Settings > Apps and tell us what is mentioned below Open Supported links entry. If it is Don't open in this app, than you know the problem now.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Under the **Open supported links** entry, **Open in this app** option is selected.